# How do I instantiate a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, instance

I'm making some maths classes for a project in Java. I have a Vector3 class, but I will also need Vector4 and Vector2, but obviously I don't want to copy paste my code 3 times.

So what I did is a Vector class that will be the mother class of all vectors. I could just have the Vector class with no child, but I prefer having these child classes because I can add specific things on them, like euler angles operations in Vector3 and also I want to use Vector4 as a mother class for Quaternion. Anyways, here is my simplified Vector class:

```java
public class Vector {

    public double[] values;

    public Vector(double[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int getLength() { 
        return values.length; 
    }

    public static <T extends Vector> T multiply(T vector, double k) {

        double[] values = new double[vector.getLength()];
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            values[i] = k* vector.values[i];
        return new T(values);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Vector3 extends Vector {
    public Vector3(double[] values) {
        super(values);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler won't let me instantiate a T: "Type parameter T cannot be instantiated directly". But I need this T because I need the returned vector to be the same type as the sent one.

If I do new Vector2(4,2).multiply(42), I need to get a Vector2 and not a Vector. I could also make a multiply method in Vector2 that calls the Vector multiply and then copies the values in a Vector2 but 1. it's awful, 2. that would imply a lot of copy paste between the child vectors, 3. I need performance, so that's not ideal.

I know I can use reflection to solve the problem, but these methods are performance critical so I have to keep it as simple as possible.

I also thought about altering the vector in parameter so I don't have to instantiate a new one, but that's a really bad idea because it can cause weird behavior.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is performance critical you might actually think about having the multiply method altering the state of the vector instead of creating a new one. In my opinion, it is not weird, as long as it is a deterministic and documented behavior.

For an immutable vector class, however, you need to [`clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) the vector.

```
public class Vector implements Cloneable {
    // not a good idea to make it public, if you don't want any changes here
    private double[] values;

    public static <T extends Vector> T multiply(T vector, double k) {
        Vector temp = vector.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.values.length; i++)
            temp.values[i] = k * temp.values[i];
        // the clone method guarantees that 'temp' is of type T,
        // but since it is not generic, the compiler cannot check it
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
        T result = (T)temp;
        return result;
    }

    protected Vector clone() {
        try {
            Vector vector = (Vector)super.clone();
            vector.values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
            return vector;
        } catch (final CloneNotSupportedException exc) {
            // this is a weird design choice of `Object.clone()`, too,
            // but back then, we did not have annotations or anything equivalent
            throw new AssertionError("we forgot to implement java.lang.Cloneable", exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would seem to be to have an instance method on the `Vector` class:

```
Vector make(double[] values) {
  return new Vector(values);
}
```

which you then override in each of the subclasses, making use of a covariant return type:

```
class Vector3 extends Vector {
  //...

  @Override Vector3 make(double[] values) {
    return new Vector3(values);
  }

  //...
}
```

And you can then invoke this in your multiply method.

```
return vector.make(values);
```

---

But honestly, I wouldn't try to encode the length of the vector into the type. What happens when you need a vector with 57032 elements? You surely wouldn't want to create a specific class for that, would you? What happens if you have two different subclasses of `Vector` that have the same numbers of elements: are they compatible (e.g. for addition) or not?

Languages which deal with vectors much more naturally (e.g. MATLAB) don't build it into the type; ask yourself if you *really* need it here.

Comment: You can represent a vector with 57032 through the base `Vector` class. However, instead of subclasses one could also include specific (for example euler angles operations) in the base class and throw an `IllegalStateException` if the vector is not of the appriopriate length.

Comment: @Izruo yes, you can use the base class. But then, once you've gone to the base class, it's hard to get back to the specific classes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the two sentences I wrote are completely independent. The first one bases on the idea of multiple classes (and there is obviously no point in having a `Vector3` with 57032 elements), while the second one bases on only one class ('instead of subclasses').

Comment: @Izruo I was only commenting on your first sentence.

Comment: This solution works but I have to make Vector abstract to apply it. So I can't instantiate it anymore, and it's not good because I want to be able to create Vectors of any size without creating a new class.
I tried using an interface with the make method. But it forces me to replace T extends Vector by IVector (the new interface). So all the methods I use in the multiply method must be in the interface (getLength() for example). That's not ideal but it's not that bad.

Comment: @KubbyDev you don't need to make it abstract: you can simply make it return `new Vector(values)`.